# Is there an API Explorer for Classic API NVP requests

Tags: paypal

It seems that the [PayPal API Explorer](https://devtools-paypal.com/apiexplorer/PayPalAPIs) only supports testing SOAP requests. Is there a tool I can use to test Name-Value Pair requests?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We have an "unofficial" tool that can be used to test the classic APIs in SOAP or NVP. This site is not supported by PayPal and I strongly advise to only use this with sandbox credentials.

The link is:

http://ccaples.com/index.php/api-s/paypal-nvp/nvp-quick-test

Regards,

Will